# Audit log file not created in k3s cluster after enabling API server audit logging

Tags: kubernetes, k3s

I have a 6 node k3s cluster (3 master/control-plane nodes and 3 worker nodes) that I'm trying to enable API service audit logging for. I'm running k3s version v1.25.0+k3s1 on Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS.

Following the instructions [here](https://docs.k3s.io/security/hardening-guide#api-server-audit-configuration), I performed the following steps on all master nodes:

1. created a log directory with `mkdir -p -m 700 /var/lib/rancher/k3s/server/logs`
2. added an `audit.yaml` at `/var/lib/rancher/k3s/server` with the following contents:

```yaml
apiVersion: audit.k8s.io/v1
kind: Policy
rules:
- level: Metadata
```

3. added the required arguments to the `k3s.service` systemd unit file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Lightweight Kubernetes
Documentation=https://k3s.io
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=notify
ExecStartPre=-/sbin/modprobe br_netfilter
ExecStartPre=-/sbin/modprobe overlay
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/k3s server \
    --disable servicelb \
    --disable traefik \
    --write-kubeconfig-mode 644 \
    --kube-controller-manager-arg bind-address=0.0.0.0 \
    --kube-proxy-arg metrics-bind-address=0.0.0.0 \
    --kube-scheduler-arg bind-address=0.0.0.0 \
    --etcd-expose-metrics true \
    --kubelet-arg containerd=/run/k3s/containerd/containerd.sock \
    --kube-apiserver-arg audit-log-path=/var/lib/rancher/k3s/server/logs/audit.log \
    --kube-apiserver-arg audit-policy-file=/var/lib/rancher/k3s/server/audit.yaml
KillMode=process
Delegate=yes
# Having non-zero Limit*s causes performance problems due to accounting overhead
# in the kernel. We recommend using cgroups to do container-local accounting.
LimitNOFILE=1048576
LimitNPROC=infinity
LimitCORE=infinity
TasksMax=infinity
TimeoutStartSec=0
Restart=always
RestartSec=5s

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

4. finally I `systemctl daemon-reload` and `systemctl restart k3s.service`

After doing this I ran some `kubectl` commands and waited for an `audit.log` file to generate but it never did.

I went on to try several other things including:

- moving the `audit.yaml` to `/var/lib/rancher/k3s/server/manifests/policy.yaml` and updating `audit-policy-file` arg accordingly - I learned files in this directory are loaded automatically and this wasn't the appropriate place for the file so I moved it back to `/var/lib/rancher/k3s/server/`
- setting the args as `--kube-apiserver-arg=audit-log-path=/var/lib/rancher/k3s/server/logs/audit.log` with an "=" instead of space between `arg` and `audit` for both apiserver args - I learned either is fine so this shouldn't be the issue.
- reviewing logs with `journalctl -u k3s --since "15 minutes ago"` and `grep "Aug 16 13:" /var/log/syslog` but there are no apparent errors related to audit logging
- checking file and folder permissions which look fine - No "permission" related errors in the logs.
- changing the `audit/policy.yaml` to different things such as:

```yaml
apiVersion: audit.k8s.io/v1
kind: Policy
rules:
# do not log requests to the following 
- level: None
  nonResourceURLs:
  - "/healthz*"
  - "/logs"
  - "/metrics"
  - "/swagger*"
  - "/version"

# limit level to Metadata so token is not included in the spec/status
- level: Metadata
  omitStages:
  - RequestReceived
  resources:
  - group: authentication.k8s.io
    resources:
    - tokenreviews

# extended audit of auth delegation
- level: RequestResponse
  omitStages:
  - RequestReceived
  resources:
  - group: authorization.k8s.io
    resources:
    - subjectaccessreviews

# log changes to pods at RequestResponse level
- level: RequestResponse
  omitStages:
  - RequestReceived
  resources:
  - group: "" # core API group; add third-party API services and your API services if needed
    resources: ["pods"]
    verbs: ["create", "patch", "update", "delete"]

# log everything else at Metadata level
- level: Metadata
  omitStages:
  - RequestReceived
```

At this point, nothing I've tried seems to work and I seem to be making things worse by constantly reloading and restarting k3s. Has anyone faced a similar issue with k3s audit logging? Are there steps or configurations I might be missing?

**UPDATE:** For anyone interested, the problem appears to have been with the way `ExecStart` is formatted. I don't know what it didn't like about it but putting it all on one line fixed all the issues I was having.

Comment: what's in `cat /etc/rancher/k3s/config.yaml` ?

Comment: @RickRackow I only have a `k3s.yaml` in that diretory and its a copy of my kube config.

Comment: In case that is what you were interested in, there is nothing special in there just the cert data and the server set as `server: https://127.0.0.1:6443`.